# Does size modifiers reverse or apply overtop when wildshaping?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, druid, wild-shape, creature-size

OK, so, let's say I have a small creature, like a gnome, who is a druid. They wild shape into a large-sized animal.

Small creatures have these size stats:
+1 AC, -1 CMB, -1 CMD, +4 Stealth Checks

Large Creatures have these size stats:
-1 AC, +1 CMB, +1 CMD, -4 Stealth Checks

My question is, when wild shaping, do you reverse the small size mods and then apply the large ones, or just apply the large ones on top of whatever already exists?

ie: Would a small creature wild shaping into a large creature look like this:
-1 AC, +1 CMB, +1 CMD, -4 Stealth Checks

...or like this?:
-1 AC, +1 CMB, +1 CMD, -4 Stealth Checks, -1 AC, +1 CMB, +1 CMD, -4 Stealth Checks

Answer (score 3):

Your size modifiers would reverse from small to whatever size you wild shaped into, as you are that animal/plant/elemental. (Small to large would make your modifiers -1 AC +1 CMB +1 CMD and -4 to stealth checks.) Basically, you would remove your previous modifiers then add the new modifiers for as long as you are transformed with wild shape.

Answer (score 1):

You do reverse the small size mods, or... you face the problem from a completely different angle.
Let's say you're calculating your AC and you're a gnome. You're small so you get that +1.
Now, let's take your morphed, large form and let's calculate your AC again. You get a -1 (but you're not getting the +1 so it's just like you "reversed it").

Same goes for all the other size bonus/penalties