# How does wild shape work when adjusting ability scores and performing natural attacks?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, druid

I'm curious because the *Wild Shape* ability states that it works as the *Beast Shape* spell.  The spell simply states that it adjusts certain ability scores (seems to only adjust size related ability scores).

Does this mean if a Druid transforms into a given animal in keeps most of its ability scores as they are and only makes the changes in the *Beast Shape* spell description?

Also, does the shape changer receive all the animal's natural attacks and adjust them according to the shape changer's scores such as BAB and STR modifier?

Comment: Related, but not a duplicate: [Does size modifiers reverse or apply overtop when wildshaping?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/32025/52137)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for your first question yes, you only change scores based on the *beast shape* spell (mainly just size modifiers, you can look at the link in the comments to see answers on how that works).

As for your second question, yes, you gain all of the creatures natural attacks and adjust them to your modifiers.